# How to draw circles of variable sizes on touch using Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Circles of variable sizes will be drawn on blank.png (800 X 800) on touch and in run time. On touch, the coordinates (the positions of x-axis and y-axis coordinates in runtime on touch) will be stored in two variables myCoordx and myCoordy in began event. When a user moves his/her fingers on screen, circle will be drawn based on calculated radius and coordinates. Now the error keeps on appearing. Please help me to debug this code.

```
Runtime error
    d:\corona projects\enterframeevent\main.lua:14: attempt to index global 'drawCircle' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    d:\corona projects\enterframeevent\main.lua:14: in main chunk
```

This is my main.lua file.

```
local screen = display.newImage( "blank.png")

function drawCircle:touch(event)    
    if event.phase == "began" then
        local myCoordx = event.x    
        local myCoordy = event.y

    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        local rad = (event.x - myCoordx) ^ 2   
        local myCircle = display.newCircle(event.x, event.y, rad )
        myCircle:setFillColor( 1, 0, 1 )

    end  
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", drawCircle )
```

Comment: The code you posted can't be right for two reasons: line 14 points to the `end` just before `Runtime`. The error message could for line 16, but line 3 will cause problem first. Please edit your post to put the actual code sample with which you are able to reproduce the error, and update the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you try to add `:touch` method to `drawCircle`, but you don't define it anywhere. You should init it to something at very least an empty table - i.e. `{}` or use relevant Corona method to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could go with something like this:

```
-- I think you should define these outside the function
-- since they'll be out of scope in the "moved" phase
local myCoordx = 0
local myCoordy = 0

-- Moved this declaration outside the function
-- so it can be reused, and removed
local myCircle

function onTouch(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then

        myCoordx = event.x    
        myCoordy = event.y

    elseif event.phase == "moved" then

        local rad = (event.x - myCoordx) ^ 2   

        -- Keep in mind that this line will draw a new circle everytime you fall into the "moved" phase, keeping the old one
        -- if i understood well, this is not what you want
        -- local myCircle = display.newCircle(event.x, event.y, rad )

        -- Try this instead, removing the old display object...
        if myCircle then
            myCircle:removeSelf()
            myCircle = nil
        end

        -- ...and adding it again
        myCircle = display.newCircle(event.x, event.y, rad )
        myCircle:setFillColor( 1, 0, 1 )

    end  
end

-- Since "drawCircle" is not defined, point it directly to a function (in this case, "onTouch")
-- Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", drawCircle )
Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
```

Didn't have the chance to test the code on Simulator, i'll try it later and update the answer if needed.

**UPDATE:**
Tested it, and it works as i expected.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, the code posted can't write, or the error message is wrong. I'll assume the error is wrong, because the statement `function drawCircle:touch(event)` on line 3 attempts to add a method called `touch(self)` to a `drawCircle` table; yet the code does not create this table anywhere. You are either missing `drawCircle = display.newSomething...`, OR you could simply use a function not a method:

```
function touch(event)    
    ...
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", touch)
```

The latter works only because your touch function doesn't use the keyword `self`, which is an implicitly created variable for methods.